# 2 PDF-fields for calculations, field 3 = field 1 - field 2

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I'm using an Adobe PDF in which are fields.
Some read-only and are filled with values through an xdp.
But some of the pdf-fields can be edited and filled after the merge from the PDF with the xdp-file.

Now I want the result from field 1 - field 2 in field 3

```js
field3.setAction( "Calculate", ‘AFSimple_Calculate("SUM", field1, field2)’ ==> can only sum

_decSumL("field1","-field2"); ==> old function which worked in an older version, but not anymore


field3.setAction( "Calculate", ‘AFSimple_Calculate("SUM", field1, field2)’
```

or

```js
_decSumL("field1","-field2"); vers
```